# JPA mapping native query result to non entity DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

I have a complex native query and I am trying to map its result to a non-entity DTO class. I am trying to use `JPA`'s `SqlResultSetMapping` with `ConstructorResult`

My DTO class

```
@Data
public class Dto {

    private Long id;

    private String serial;

    private Long entry;

    private int numOfTasks;
}
```

My entity class, which has the repository interface that I will call this native query result.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "itemDetailsMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Dto.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "ID"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "SERIAL"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "ENTRY"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "TASKS")
                        }
                )
        }
)

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getItemDetails", query = "complex query is here", resultSetMapping = "itemDetailsMapping")
@Entity
@Data
public class Item {}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    ...     

    List<Dto> getItemDetails();

}
```

When I call the `getItemDetails()` from `ItemRepository` I have the following error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property itemDetails found for type Item

What is the proper way to use `SqlResultSetMapping` and `ConstructorResult`
and solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use named queries the name of the named query must have the entity name as prefix:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Item.getItemDetails", 
                 query = "complex query is here", resultSetMapping = "itemDetailsMapping")
```

Then the interface method must have the same name as the named query without the prefix:

```
List<Dto> getItemDetails();
```

-

Read more about Spring Data JPA and named queries in the reference doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries

Comment: Actually, that's my bad, My method name is getItemDetails but I had to add Item. prefix at the beginning of the name. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Any idea why you are not using the RowMapper?

Comment: @Anil Maybe because SqlResultSetMapping is JPA standard?